# Как переместить значения из таблицы sqlite в список python (flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite, flask

Я хочу извлечь данные из таблицы sqlite в список и передать этот самый список в html-шаблон. Я попробовал это сделать так:

```
query = "SELECT * from columnes where name_music='{name}'".format(name=name)
query1 = "SELECT * from article where name_music='{name}'".format(name=name)
articule = cursor.execute(query1)
articule = articule.fetchall()
d = cursor.execute(query)
d = d.fetchall()
print(articule[0][0])
return render_template('composition.html', comp=d, comp1=articule)
```

Однако,когда я пытаюсь вывести элемент с помощью print у меня выводится ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно,кто-нибудь знает - как это исправить? Или кто-нибудь знает другие способы извлечь данные из базы данных?
Заранее спасибо!
P.S.  Так же хотелось бы сказать,что в таблице article лежит один элемент(она не пустая).

P.S.S если выводить articule[0] получается очень интересно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть сначала он выводит всё,но потом ругается на этот же вывод

Comment: Напишите для начала просто ```print( articule )```, давайте посмотрим чему оно равно

Comment: Зачем у вас код два раза продублирован? )

Comment: alex, в этом случае ничего не выводится

Comment: @CrazyElf, поправил

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import sqlite3 as sql
conn = sql.connect('mydb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
name = 'music'

cur.execute(
    "select * from arcticle where name_music = ?;", [name]
)
article = [*cur.fetchall()]  # or list(cur.fetchall())
# Ну и так далее
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно быть:

```
query1 = "SELECT * from article where name_music='{name}'".format(name=name)
cursor.execute(query1)
data = cursor.fetchall()
print(data[0][0])
```

Comment: Та же ошибка.У меня в третей строчке есть fetchall,поэтому вряд ли это бы что-то поменяло.

Comment: Может быть неверно подставляешь тип данных в запрос и он ничего не возвращает. Попробуй: query = "SELECT * from article where name_music=%s", и выполнить cursor.execute(query , (name,)). Либо возвращается не кортеж, тогда попробуй: print(data[0])

Comment: во втором случае получается очень интересный вывод

Answer (score 0):

Тут не нужно вручную формировать строку запроса, используйте биндинги (binding). Это обезопасит от sql-инъекций и оставит заботу о экранировании строки на драйвер

- Например, у вас запрос формируется вручную `SELECT * from columnes where name_music='{name}'`, а кто-то передает в `name` такую строку `' or 1=1 or ''='` и у вас получится запрос, который вернет все записи таблицы (это sql-инъекция):

  ```sql
  SELECT * from columnes where name_music='' or 1=1 or ''=''
  ```

Пример:

```
articule = cursor.execute("SELECT * from article where name_music=?", [name]).fetchall()
columnes = cursor.execute("SELECT * from columnes where name_music=?", [name]).fetchall()
print(len(articule), articule)
print(len(columnes), columnes)

return render_template('composition.html', comp=columnes, comp1=articule)
```

---

**PS.**

Вторым параметром в `execute` передается коллекция, обычно это кортеж, но на один элемент он путающим `(name,)`, поэтому использовал список `[name]`